# Turn off md5hash (fingerprinting) suffix in rails production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, requirejs, asset-pipeline, sprockets

In my app, `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake assets:precompile` generates `main-fingerprint.css` with svg files referenced inside Rails helpers by names not suffixed with fingerprints (MD5 digest), and the same task but with `RAILS_ENV=production` generates the names with the MD5 suffixes.

I don't want the suffixes, because I use `.sprockets-manifest-md5hash.json`, which includes mappings from nondigest to digest names.
And, as [per docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets):

> This is used by the Rails helper methods to avoid handing the mapping requests back to Sprockets

The `config.assets` settings for both environments are identical and I couldn't find anything interesting in `application.rb` or `environment.rb`. On production, how do I generate compiled css referencing images from within rails helpers without the digest part? Currently we're just hacking it by passing `RAILS_ENV=test` on a build job, but maybe there's a better way?

For optimization of javascripts and stylesheets we use `requirejs` and `requirejs-rails`. However, afaik they don't care about the digests, which is a sprockets job to generate and suffix them (always on).

Comment: rails guide has [a section on this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-digests-off). Have you tried it?

Comment: Of course. This option is imho slightly misdocumented - `assets.digest` controls only whether assets will be HTTP-requested by filename including the digest or not. This setting does not control the asset filenames. As a matter of fact, there's no setting for it (you have to write [a custom rake task](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49#issuecomment-20535134) or use [this gem](https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets)). Check this [issue](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49) for more info.